# Laravel running Python script return error libraries not found

Tags: python, laravel, pyodbc, laravel-8, symfony-process

I am running a Python script in Laravel using the new process and `process->run()` method.

```php
$process = new Process(['python3', 'public/python/ARIMA/' . $scriptName]);
$process->setTimeout(180);
$process->run();
```

The problem is that the process->run it throwing the following error.

```
python3: can't open file 'public/python/ARIMA/KarlStorzARIMA.py': [Errno 2]
```

No such file or directory when I change the path and use the absolute path will return the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/home/zantezu/PhpstormProjects/case-medical/public/python/ARIMA/KarlStorzARIMA.py",
> line 2, in import pyodbc ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

The code to run the process is placed inside of the `HomeController.php`.
I have another python script running in a different controller without any problem, and it uses PyODBC too. I'm not sure what the problem could be, I did change the chmod of the folder already, and if I do pip install PyODBC, it says that it is already installed. I have Anaconda installed on my PC. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Instead of `'python3'`, pass the full path to the Python executable in whatever virtual environment contains the libraries you need.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with corrupted python paths / presence of conda on the pc, removing all the python distro installed, cleaning up all the folders associated with python and reloading it fixed the issue.